# trouble with scale graphic

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with android, version 5.1. (lolipop).

When I tried to scale bitmap using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`, app was send to me an error:

> **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference**

I doesn't know why this is doing. On newest versions of android this working good.

```
ImageView imageView = this.menuPageModel.getBackground();
int id;
Bitmap bitmap;
Context context = appModel.getContext();

id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("background", "drawable", context.getPackageName());

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);

bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, appModel.getScreenWidth(), appModel.getScreenHeight(), false);

imageView.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(appModel.getScreenWidth(), appModel.getScreenHeight()));

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I fixed that. Problem was size of image 300 x 400 in resources folder. Can anyone test this theory?